# This pointer differs from the pointer the methode was called on

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I wrote an Application in C++ that is crashing some times, because of an object-methode that stores an invalid this pointer! When i debug my application and look at the call-stack there is function *func1* and the following is *func2*. In the first function the pointer is valid, but in the second one, where the this pointer should have the same address as the pointer in the first function, the this pointer is pointing to some invalid memory address:

```
void obj1::func1( obj2* o ){
  //Pointer o is valid and correctely initialized when i debug my Application
  o->func2();
}

void obj2::func2(){
  //Here i do a call on the this pointer. The this pointer is invalid and so my
  //Application is crashing. How can i have a different this pointer then the 
  //pointer i was calling on. I can't imagine how this can happen.
  this->someCall();
}
```

My application is using different threads and so i had the idea that i perhabs delete my object in some other thread that is not working like it sould, but so the this pointer would not be changed - please tell me if i'm wrong. I have no idea how this error can happen.

Thanks for your help.
Denis

Comment: Possibly this is stack corruption somewhere in func1.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant portions from the class interface of `obj1` and `obj2`? And why are you calling it as `this->someCall()` instead of `someCall()`. Does `obj2` derive from other classes?

Comment: please provide minimal source that compiles and shows the problem you are having.

Comment: @rhalbersma i dont realy do call this->someCall() but this->obj3->someCall() - i only simplified the problem because the problem is the this pointer.

Comment: @NoSenceEtAl i can't show you compilable code because it's a realy big project and the error only appears some times - only in one of many cases this error appears.

Comment: This cannot happen without either your code having undefined behaviour, or your compiler having a bug. If you can reproduce the problem, you should be able to systematically remove code from your system until you have a minimal test case (this is work you have to do). Then if you still don't understand why your code is failing, you can give this minimal test case to us, and it should contain enough information for us to say either "you have undefined behaviour *there*", or "your compiler definitely has a bug". Without a minimal test case, this question is impossible to answer properly.

Comment: btw problems with reproducing bug... smells like a race condition

Comment: @Mankrase The big problem is that i can't reproduce this bug. The func1 and func2 methodes are called a thousend times a day, while the error is only happening 1 or 2 times a day and it is not happening after a specific runtime, but it seems like it's happening by 'random'. When i see that the software crashed because of this error, then i can debug it and i see what happend, but i can't find the cause - so how can i reproduce a bug if i don't know why it appears?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The func 1 is the entry point of a new thread for a task my programm is doing. In this stack the hidden-this pointer is passed by my call. So how can there be race condition in the stack, if there is a seperate one for each thread?

Comment: @DenisD - first comment : like Mankarse told you : "If you can reproduce the problem, you should be able to systematically remove code from your system until you have a minimal test case (this is work you have to do)"

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code the way you provided.  But I think that the answer is in your question: you are using multiple threads.  Once you have more than one thread you need to check your thread model and how access to memory gets synchronized.  Unfortunately, it is up to you to determine to figure what exactly happens as the problem does not seem to be related the way this particular code is written.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this problem is due to multi-threading issues.

The computer performs takes a short break between doing line A and line B, and ends up likely deleting the object that 'o' points to.

```
void obj1::func1( obj2* o ){
  o->func2(); //Line A
}

void obj2::func2(){
  this->someCall(); //Line B
}
```

You will want to locate all places in the code that deconstruct (explicitly or implicitly), the object and make sure they can't delete the object while it is still being pointed at.

You could enforce this by using smart pointers or just by synchronizing operations on the object with locks.